# What are some examples of systems which have non-zero entropy at zero temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, entropy

At zero temperature, the entropy of generic systems need not vanish, but often seems to in practice.  I would like to know some concrete examples where $S\neq 0$ at $T=0$.

A very high-energy flavored scenario where $S\neq 0$ at $T=0$ is the case of extremal black holes, where $S=\frac{\rm Area}{4G_N}\neq 0$.  I believe glassy systems (and frustrated systems, more generally) also have non-trivial zero-$T$ entropy.

What are some additional systems which have $S\neq 0$ at $T=0$? References are appreciated.

Comment: [Ice-type models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice-type_model) provide famous examples.

Answer (score -1):

According to the third law of thermodynamics, any system approaching 0 Kelvin approaches a constant value of entropy. Crystalline systems approach zero entropy state, while amorphous systems do not reach a state of 0 entropy, rather just a state of constant entropy.

Most solids would be classified under amorphous, and hence we can say most will not have zero entropy at 0 K. Glasses and gels are some examples